# View Templates doesn't get rendered with $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I'm trying out to switch the views for different routes. I began with this very basic setup. But my view templates doesn't get rendered at all. There are no errors though. Here goes my files
The js file defining the routes.

```
var var mainapp = angular.module("routing", ['ngRoute']);
mainapp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
$routeProvider.when('/students', { templateUrl: 'students.html', controller: 'students' })
              .otherwise({redirectTo:'home.html'});
}]);
mainapp.controller('students', ['$scope',function ($scope) {
$scope.message = "Hello,This is students controller";
}]);
```

The templates are just simple for understanding purpose

Students.js

```
<div class="container">
{{message}}
</div>
```

I have been trying to keep the html template files in different folders and trying but I couldn't get the resullt displayed. Hence for now I kept everything in Scripts folder. The project structure is very basic and simple.[image: Project structure] I'm using Visual Studio 2012(tried on VS 2017, with anngularjs version 1.6.2

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the path for the templateUrl.  It also looks like your otherwise is a bit off.  You said your html files are in the `Scripts` folder so my code is based off of that.  This should work for you, if not something else is going on.

```
$routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: 'Scripts/home.html' })
              .when('/students', { templateUrl: 'Scripts/students.html', controller: 'students' })
              .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
```

Comment: Yes I tried to specify the templateUrl as mentioned, but still nothing appears. But when I specifically request for `students.html`, it comes up with binding not evaluated and even `home.html` is accessible and show up the content.

Comment: Are there some error messages in the console?  If so can you post them?